# Image in WPF Button not Visible at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button

I have the following XAML and my particular problem relates to the image that is to be displayed on the button

```xml
<Button  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Grid.Row="1">
    <Image VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Height="16 " Width="16"  
      Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/UserCost2013Open16.png"
    />
</Button>
```

The image properties have `Build Action = Resource`, and `Copy to output directory = Do not copy`. The image shows in the designer but not at runtime.

How do I get the button image to appear at **runtime**?

Comment: Try setting the build action to `Content`. It may be helpful

Comment: Tried that too. That does not help either...

Comment: What could possibly help is checking the output console in Visual Studio when debugging the application. Sometimes it shows helpful errors (e.g. binding errors etc.)

Comment: Usually your URI will most likely be the issue, as Daniel says look at the output window, there will most likely be complaints about the image source not found or something of that nature.

Comment: set the build-action to content and set 'copy to output directory' to 'copy always' or 'copy if newer'

Comment: @Tomtom tried all those no joy. I have since check the 'Output' at runtime, and mscorlib.dll was throwing an IOException but giving no other information...

Comment: Note to editors: [code formatting should be reserved for **code**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755/191410).

Comment: Here is also an [explaination from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx "URIs for WPF") about the URI scheme used for WPF in case you want to understand the underlying structure.

Comment: @Killercam: What exception was that? An `InvalidCastException` by any chance? I am trying to debug a similar problem, and seeing whether the symptoms match exactly with this one might help me (and other future visitors) find a solution.

Comment: Apologies @O.R.Mapper I have been on holiday. Yes, if I remember correctly this was an `InvalidCastException`...

Comment: @Killercam: I have solved my particular problem; see my other comment and the link if you're interested.

Comment: @user2883257 Solved. Instead of Source="/Resources/goback.png" I was using Source=Resources/goback.png. Settings: CopyIfNewer and Content.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Change the build action to `Resource`.
Also your pack url is wrong.  Either use:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Resource/UserCost2013Open16.png"
```

or simply

```
Source="/Resource/UserCost2013Open16.png"
```

Comment: I have just re-added the image using the designer properties panel which I did in the first place and it provided a different URI to the one I had and was like the top one you have shown - this did not work. I re-added the image as a resource - again no luck. I _then_ re-added the image _again_ - this gave me a URI like the bottom one show... Taadaa! It worked, why this happened I have no idea, but it is good to know in the future. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Killercam: I have now experienced something very similar; have a look at my *EDIT3* in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022707/how-to-set-image-resource-uri-from-code-behind/21024049) for a possible explanation of why re-adding may be helpful (though not one for why it worked for you only on the second attempt).

Comment: `pack://application:,,,/...` does not appear to be liked very much by .XAML at runtime. Throws an error - "unrecognized/invalid blah blah". I have a `UIDomain` project with all the views, presenters, models and images. It seems that the `Resources/*.png` is expected to be in the `views/ ... ... /Resources/img.png` directory when it is more like `../Resources/img.png`

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: Just Right Click on Image and select Properties and change "Build Action" to "Resource".

Answer (score 37):

There are 2 Solutions: 

1: Change the settings of the image:

```
Build Action = Content
Copy to output directory = Copy if newer
Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/UserCost2013Open16.png"
```

2: When Using ***application*** instead of ***siteoforigin*** in the source path, you have to possible ways:

a) Image will be in a SubFolder called "Resources" and .exe file will be small

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/UserCost2013Open16.png"
Build Action = Content
Copy to output directory = Copy if newer
```

b) Image will be included in the .exe and no Subfolder with imagefile will exist

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/UserCost2013Open16.png"
Build Action = Resource
Copy to output directory = Copy if newer
```

Comment: Solution 2 works. `Copy to output directory` is not necessary in my case.

Comment: Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you have set your `Build Action` to `Resource`.

Use the [`URI-PACK-FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf):

`pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.xaml` or `pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml` or
`pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml`

Those are the most common examples.

Also, in my case it was still not showing.

`Clean & Rebuild` **NOT just Build** fixed it for me (VS 2019)!

Comment: So you have the exact same setup like in the initial question and you didn't need to change the build action nor copy settings or the source path?

Comment: Yes. `BuildAction` & `UriPack` was right. Image did not show => `Clean & Rebuild` and it worked.

Comment: The problem is `Image in WPF Button not Visible at Runtime
` that was the case at my side and above is my solution. I don't care about -2 rep but I really got no idea what ur problem with this is .. ?!

Comment: `set your Build Action to Resource` was enought for me

Comment: This worked for me, using VS 22 and .net 6

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had the images in a separate project named `Common` and the images were under a folder named `Resources` in this project. In my other project, I added a reference to `Common` and set the source of the images like this:

```
<Image Source="/Common;component/Resources/anImage.png"/>
```

The images have the `Build Action` set to `Resource` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`. However, for some strange reason it wasn't working until I deleted every assembly file in my solution and made a `Clean Solution` and `Build Solution`. Not sure why, but it all started working at runtime once I rebuilt everything. I still can't figure out why it was working at Design Time though.

Comment: Adding the `component` string into the Source path was critical to getting my images to display at run time.

Comment: Although having Content and Always Copy used to work for me, after moving to a different machine, I only saw the images/fonts in the designer and not at run-time. Changing them to Resource and Do not Copy fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio do these steps

1. Add your image to a folder named as you want, in this example I created an `Assets` named folder.
2. Then set the image's property to `Resource` in the `Build Action`.
3. Then select the image in the folder and drag and then drop the into `<MenuItem.Icon>` and it should path properly.

[image: Drop Image into project, Set as Resource then drop onto page]

- Note you may need to Rebuild the project, the compiler sometimes doesn't recognize new resources as a need to rebuild.

Answer (score 6):

Go to your image in the resources folder, right click on the image, go to properties, click on the Build Action property, and change it from None to Resource. That'll work.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Why doesn't MS's official documents say this!??!?!? :)

Answer (score 4):

You should add any thing inside **Solution Explorer** of Visual Studio.
Instead of just copying the image to folder in Windows Explorer, press Right Click on any folder in Solution Explorer go to **Add > Existing Item...** and select the path to your resource to be added.

Answer (score 4):

I defined my image as next:

```
<Image Source="/Resources/Images/icon.png"/>
```

The image is displayed in *Visual Studio* designer but no image is displayed when I launched the app! It made me nuts!
I tried all *Build Action*s with clean/build, no luck.

In my case the problem is caused by the fact that the control (which uses *Image*) and the app itself are in different projects. *Resources/Images* folder is in the *Controls* project. As result the app attempted to find icon.png in its own Debug folder, but actually it is in *Controls*' Debug folder.

So two solutions work for me:

1) put *Resources/Images* in the app's project (not so good when there are several projects which use controls from *Controls* project, but it works)

2) specify the name of Controls project explicitly inside *Image*:

```
<Image Source="/Controls;component/Resources/Images/icon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new folder and put your pictures in the new folder and write this in XAML

```
<Image Source="/newfolder/icon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the "build action" to "Resource" and the "copy to output directory" to "Do not copy" has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone arrives here and has the image set as "Resource" and "Do not copy" and it still doesn't work, I was able to fix this by toggling Build Action for the image off of "Resource" and then back again.

Answer (score -6):

**Source="file:///D:/100x100.jpg"/>** works for me.