# Displaying images with build action set to 'content' within WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, embedded-resource

I have a main project in `WinForms` and I display pictures within this project with build action set to '*content*'. I got a `WPF` window to work within my `WinForms` project, the only thing that currently does not work is displaying an image with build action set to '*content*' within my `WPF` window. If I change the build action to '*resource*' I can display the images just fine. This does break the functionality in my `WinForms` project unfortunately.

So is there any way I can display an image within `WPF` with build action set to '*content*'? Without breaking my `WinForms` project of course, because I show the same image both in `WinForms` and `WPF`.

EDIT:
I found a solution, [see my answer further down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551490/5368689).

Comment: Do you have the image set to "Copy always"?  Are you sure the content file is present where the app thinks it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What eventually did the trick for me was shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636903) answer combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118578) answer.

I chose **solution 2a** from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636903):

> Image will be in a SubFolder called "Resources" and .exe file will be small

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/example.png"
Build Action = Content
Copy to output directory = Copy if newer
```

Then I did:

```
ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/example.png"));
image.Source = imageSource;
```